# Sort SQL Query by most recent question answered (like a forum)

Tags: php, mysql

If you're familiar with a forum, when a question is answered it moves to the top of the list. How does this SQL query work? Right now, my query is as follows:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(*) FROM tblQA Q1 WHERE Q1.intResponseID = Q2.intQAID) AS answercount, 
(SELECT cUsername FROM tblUsers tblU WHERE Q2.intPosterID = tblU.intUserID) AS username,       
(SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(dSortDateTime) = DAY(NOW()) THEN DATE_FORMAT(dSortDateTime, 'Today at %l:%i%p') 
ELSE DATE_FORMAT(dSortDateTime, '%b %e, %l:%i%p') END) AS post_time 
FROM tblQA Q2 WHERE cCategory IN ('Football','Baseball','Basketball','Hockey') 
ORDER BY dSortDateTime DESC, dSortDateTime DESC LIMIT 40
```

So, when a user responds to a question, I'd like that to bounce to the top of the question list. Right now, the way the query is running, its not doing this.

Look forward to your help.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
dSortdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: When one doing *research*, he is *omitting* all unnecessary things like usernames, concentrating on the current goal only. Making whole thing easier to understand. When one is just asking for free codez, he has to provide full information including table structures of all tables involved and description of all tables relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your schema, so I cannot give you the actual SQL, but you would need to store the time that the question was answered (or do a JOIN between the question and answer tables to get the most recent answer for each question). You then order by answer time DESC .

Comment: So, the dSortdatetime is stored with date('Y-m-d H:i:s') information. So it has the time as well. In my query, i'm sorting dSortdatetime by descending order. But, it's not working right.

Comment: What results were you expecting and what are you getting? Is it not sorting correctly?

Comment: When a question is answered, it should move the question to the top of the question list.

Comment: I get that, but what are the results coming out completely out of order? Does there seem to be some pattern to them? Would you mind posting some sample results?

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that it is not properly sorting answers that happened on the same day? If so, it is because a DATE has a granularity of a day. You probably want the column to be a DATETIME to also store the time (with a granularity of a second).